# Set a Layout to a View in Javascript

Tags: kendo-ui

I have this situation:

I have some Views and by default they have assigned a Layout for them. The problem is that in some specific cases, I need to change the Layout of some of these Views in the Javascript file.

I am using this way:

$("#tabstrip-dash").setAttribute('data-layout', 'mobile-tabstrip-layout2');

This solution works only if I reload the application, but I want to change it instantly.

Is there any way to set the new Layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer might be something like:

```
app.navigate("#someId")
```

I got this info from here: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mobile/general-discussions/how-to-switch-views-programatically.aspx

Note, in a test I got this working, but in my main project I have *not*. I'm seeing the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ". Not entirely sure whats going on, but there are other reports of it (in case this happens to anyone else).